# iOS Keyboard - Capitalise 'done' button

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone

I am using 'UIKeyboardTypeDefault' keyboard type for my UITextfields.

The done button for the keyboard appears in lowercase as 'done'.
Is there anyway to make this a capitalised as 'Done' ?

Comment: Have you specified `returnKeyType` for the textfield? Show some code

Comment: How you are adding done button if you specified `returnKeyType = .done` then it is in  format as you described in question

Comment: return type is specified and the done button is displayed , but the button text is in lowercase . I would like it to have as 'Done'

Comment: My answer below fixes that issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73335844/132745

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the POD - > **IQKeyboardManagerSwift**
**LINK** -->

pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift', :git =>
    'https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager.git'

This is very useful pod for handling stuff for keyboard

Answer (score 0):

We cannot set a custom text for the return key, we can only select from the available options (refer attached screenshot).
In order to set a custom text, for e.g capitalised 'done' button, you will have to create a custom keyboard. [attached screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2lRe.png)

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with the same question for tvOS for the last day or so, and figured out the solution is to get the 'to' viewController of the presented keyboard, iterate over its view hierarchy to find the button, then grab its text, capitalise it, and set it back.

Ended up with the following function:

```
fileprivate func CapitaliseReturnKey() {
let scene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first
guard
    let windowSceneDelegate = scene?.delegate as? UIWindowSceneDelegate,
    let window = windowSceneDelegate.window,
    // This gets the presented keyboard view, which is the 'to' view for the presentation transition.
    let keyboardView = window?.rootViewController?.transitionCoordinator?.view(forKey: .to)
else {
    return
}

capitaliseReturnKey(in: keyboardView)

/// Traverses the view heirarchy of the passed-in view looking for a UIButton and capitalises its title.
/// - Parameter view: the view to iterate over
func capitaliseReturnKey(in view: UIView) {
    for subView in view.subviews {
        if subView.subviews.count > 0 {
            capitaliseReturnKey(in: subView)
        }
        if subView.isKind(of: UIButton.self) {
            if let buttonView = subView as? UIButton {
                buttonView.setTitle(buttonView.currentTitle?.localizedCapitalized, for: .normal)
            }
        }
    }
}
```